# Approximate $\ln(2)$ from Maclaurin expansion

Tags: calculus

I was given a function f(x)= ln((1-x)/(1+x)) and I had to find the 9th degree polynomial and use it to approximate ln2.  I came up with the polynomial (x- (x^2)/2 + (x^3)/3 - (x^4)/4...., but I don't know what to do next to approximate ln2.

Comment: For what $x$ can you have $f(x)=\ln2$?

Comment: The polynomial quoted by OP is not Maclaurin expansion of this logarithmic function. The approximation by the proper Maclaurin series of this function is excellent because all coefficients are positive. This gives us very fast convergence.

Comment: For any $|x|<1$ we have
$$\text{arctanh}(x)=\frac{1}{2}\log\frac{1+x}{1-x}=x+\frac{x^3}{3}+\frac{x^5}{5}+\frac{x^7}{7}+\frac{x^9}{9}+\ldots $$
and by evaluating at $x=\frac{1}{3}$ we get
$$ \log 2 = 2\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{1}{(2n+1)3^{2n+1}}.$$

Answer (score 1):

To stitch the comments together, it seems that you have already found:
$$
\ln(1+x) = x - \frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{x^3}{3}  - \frac{x^4}{4} + \cdots
\tag{$*$}
$$
You were asked to find the Maclaurin series for
$$
    f(x) = \ln\left(\frac{1-x}{1+x}\right) = \ln(1-x) - \ln(1+x)
$$
but if you use (*) twice you should be able to put that together.  Now if you solve
$$
    \frac{1-x}{1+x} = \frac{1}{2}
$$
you should be able to find the right $x$ to plug in, and get a series that converges to $\ln\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) = -\ln 2$.